# How can I parse an isolated HTML Element using Jsoup?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Let us consider the following example:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    String example = "<h1></h1>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(example);
    System.out.println(doc.html());
}
```

The output of it is:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <h1></h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

How can I get an output like this:

```
<h1></h1>
```

?

I don't want the html, head and body. I want to parse and edit an **isolated** HTML Element.

Comment: i don't think it is possible. And why do you need it?

Comment: get the innerhtml of the body